# Python KeyError: 0 when i use if elif

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python to make a simple application for data mining, and I coded it in Google Colab. And I use elif on my function, here is the code

```
def data_pred(data):
  # split(data)
  X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = split(data)

  linreg = LinearRegression()
  linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_preds = linreg.predict(X_test)

  for x in range(17):
    y_test = np.insert(y_test, len(y_test), y_preds[len(y_preds)-1])
    X_test = np.insert(X_test, len(X_test), y_test[len(X_test)-1])
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(X_test.size, 1)
    y_preds = linreg.predict(X_test)


  plt.scatter(X_test, y_test)
  plt.scatter(X_test, y_preds, color='green')
  plt.plot(X_test, y_preds, color="red")
  plt.xlabel("X axis")
  plt.ylabel("Y axis")

  plt.show()

  print("nilai slope/koef/a:",linreg.coef_)
  print("nilai intercept/b :",linreg.intercept_)
  print('Data hasil prediksi :', y_preds)
  print('Data aktual :',y_test)
  print()
  print('MAPE : ', mape(y_test, y_preds))



  if data["Nama Golongan"][0] == "INDUSTRI":
    golongan = data.loc[0:23, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][44] == "INSTANSI PEMERINTAH":
    golongan = data.loc[44:67, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][88] == "NIAGA KECIL":
    golongan = data.loc[88:111, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][132] == "RUMAH MENENGAH":
    golongan = data.loc[132:155, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][176] == "RUMAH MEWAH":
    golongan = data.loc[176:119, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][220] == "SOSIAL KHUSUS":
    golongan = data.loc[220:243, "Nama Golongan"]
  elif data["Nama Golongan"][264] == "TOTAL PERBULAN":
    golongan = data.loc[264:287, "Nama Golongan"]


  more code...
```

when I run,

```
  a = this[this['Nama Golongan'] == 'INDUSTRI']
  data_pred(a)
```

I get graphic plot and the result without error. But, when I run this code

```
b = this[this['Nama Golongan'] == 'INSTANSI PEMERINTAH']
data_pred(b)
```

I get this

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, 
method, tolerance)
     2897             try:
  -> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
     2899             except KeyError as err:

  pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
  pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
  pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
  pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

I thought its cause the `elif` code, but i don't know why. can anyone tell me why and how to fix it ? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Add whole traceback error.

Comment: What is `this`?  It's not mentioned in your code at all.  Your if/elif/elif sequence, although not the right way to handle things, doesn't change the dataframe and should have no effect..

Comment: You're missing the part of the traceback that shows where this call is coming from in your code.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is coming from `if data["Nama Golongan"][0] == "INDUSTRI":`. If the dataframe is empty, there won't be a `[0]`. What are all those different indexes that are in steps of 44 all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally see the problem.  You are extracting a subset of a dataframe and passing it to this file.  So, `data["Nama Golongan"][44]` is referring to index 44, because the indicies get carried through with the subset.

The problem is that `data.loc` does NOT use the index.  It's strictly row numbers.  They're all going to start with 0.  If you ONLY want the first 23 rows, you don't need your `if` sequence at all.  Replace the whole thing with this:

```
  golongan = data.loc[0:23, "Nama Golongan"]
```

The first row, when using `loc`, is always 0.